# Is there a formal way of proposing/discussing changes to Clojure?

Tags: clojure, tacit-programming, reader-macro

Is there a formal way of proposing/discussing changes to Clojure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper place to propose language changes is the [Clojure project jira](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aissues-panel) project. Open a new issue marked as "enhancement". It's also good to check in on the #clojure freenode irc as well as searching the back issues to see if this has been proposed before

Comment: I'll drop the other part then. I searched the past proposed enhancements and didn't find anyone formally proposing this before.